# Rescuing a MacBook Pro 13-inch, Mid 2009

Tags: macbook-pro, leopard

Would appreciate help -

I have an old MBP mid-2009 shipped originally with 10.5.7 Leopard, currently running 10.6.8. I restarted recently and found a kernel panic on startup. I have tried  booting in safe mode (unsuccessful), recovery mode (unsuccessful), reset NV-RAM (unsuccessful startup) and from an OSX install disc ("unable to install OSX on this computer"). The last option yielded an actual startup screen ith language options and a box offering the option of restoring from a TM backup (I don't have one as I did not have any important data on this machine). So broadly the machine works but never gets past the grey screen with the apple logo and the time wheel.

I have another 2 newer MBPs at home and considered using target mode to resuscitate the oldest malfunctioning mac. BTW I can't eject the OSX disc from the bad mac.

Any advice on how to revive my old Mac? I'd like to keep using it as it was fine yesterday.

Thanks.

Comment: One at the time:) the disk eject should be possible in manual mode. Look carefully there should be a pinhole. Use toothpick and stick it in it to release mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Too late for this question, but why do people not consult Apple about Kernel Panics? Maybe you had other choices, yesterday.

My July 25 answer to similar question:

Read Apple's own support page, [About Kernel Panics](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts3742) , and MacWorld's [How To Troubleshoot a Kernel Panic](http://www.macworld.com/article/2027201/how-to-troubleshoot-a-kernel-panic.html). You'll be able to isolate the problem and from there, know what steps to take, many of which are quite simple.

Answer (score -1):

Boot in Target disk mode and see if you can repair the disk... if the disk is fine but the OS is corrupted then do a clean install. If you have good backups I would suggest wiping the drive and doing an install then restore your data.